# Random text with numbered variables

Tags: python, random

I'm currently trying to pick a random text stored in a numbered variable like this

```
source1 = '''First text'''

source2 = '''Second text'''     
randomtext = source[randint(1,2)]
liste_source = randomtext.rstrip('\n\r').split(" ")
```

However, it returns me an error message saying that the source is not defined... I don't understand because the source1 and source2 are defined above...

Comment: But i want to pick either source1 or source2 and I thought I had defined it with the source[rand(1,2)]

Comment: Why on earth did you think that?

Comment: poke's suggestion is the clean way to go, but FWIW if you did want to access variables like this, you can't just use [] notation, you'd have to do something wonky like `locals()['source%s' % random.randint(1,2)]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this instead:

```
source1 = "First text"
source2 = "Second text"    
randomtext = random.choice([source1, source2])
liste_source = randomtext.rstrip('\n\r').split(" ")
```

Or even simpler:

```
sources = ["first text", "second text"]
randomtext = random.choice(sources)
liste_source = randomtext.rstrip('\n\r').split(" ")
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of making multiple variables, use a list:

```
source = [
    'First text',
    'Second text'
]

randomtext = source[randint(len(source))]
```

You can also use [`random.choice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice) instead:

```
randomtext = random.choice(source)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use modified code:

```
import random
source1 = '''First text'''

source2 = '''Second text'''     
randomtext = eval("source"+str(random.randint(1,2)))

liste_source = randomtext.rstrip('\n\r').split(" ")
```